# Get solution to $y'=\frac{x-y-3}{x+y}$ that is not limited in domain?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the diffeq $$y'=\frac{x-y-3}{x+y}$$
I proceed as follows. Let
$$x(t)=t+\frac32,\qquad \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = 1,\qquad \text{d}x=\text{d}t$$
$$y(v(t))=v(t)-\frac32,\qquad \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}v} = 1,\qquad \text{d}y=\text{d}v$$
I make the substitution to get
$$v' = \frac{t-v}{t+v}$$
Now, let's set $v(t) = t \cdot u(t)$. This yields
$$tu'+u = \frac{1-u}{1+u}$$
when we perform the substitution. The equation is now separable so we integrate to get
$$u' = \frac{-u^2 - 2u + 1}{t(u+1)}\Longleftrightarrow \frac{u+1}{-u^2 -2u+1} \cdot u' = \frac{1}{t}$$
$$\implies -\frac12\ln\left(\left|-u^2-2u+1\right|\right) = \ln(|t|) + C$$
I now solve for $u$, so we have
$$\begin{align}
    -\frac12\ln\left(\left|-u^2-2u+1\right|\right) &= \ln(|t|) + C\\\\
    \ln\left(\left|-u^2-2u+1\right|\right) &= -2\ln(|t|) + C\\\\
    \left|-u^2-2u+1\right| &= \exp\left(\ln(|t|^{-2}) + C\right)\\\\
    u^2+2u-1+2 &= 2\pm  C|t|^{-2}\\\\
    (u+1)^2 &= 2\pm C|t|^{-2}\\\\
    u &= -1+\sqrt{2\pm C|t|^{-2}}
\end{align}$$
$$\implies v = -t+t\sqrt{2\pm Ct^{-2}}$$
$$\implies y+\frac32 = -\left(x-\frac32\right)+\left(x-\frac32\right)\sqrt{2\pm C\left(x-\frac32\right)^{-2}}$$
$$\implies y= -x+\left(x-\frac32\right)\sqrt{2\pm C\left(x-\frac32\right)^{-2}}$$

When I plot this in desmos, this is the graph I get
[image]
Obviously, this is missing a chunk of the domain as the slope field of the diffeq produces solutions which extend the endpoints here out.

Wolfram alpha however, gives the solutions
$$y=-x\pm\sqrt{C+x^2+2\left(\frac{x^2}2-3x\right)}$$
[image]
As seen here, these solutions successfully capture all of the domain as we vary $C$.

What did I mess up in my solution to arrive at a $y(x)$ that is missing a chunk of the domain? (and how do i get wolfram alpha's solution?)

Help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start simple using $x+y(x)=z(x)$ to get rid of the denominator. So, the equation write
$$\frac{z(x) z'(x)-2 x+3}{z(x)}=0$$ If  $z(x)\neq 0$, it looks to be more than simple.

Comment: Wait, how did you substitute $z=y+x$ into the numerator $x-y-3$?

Comment: @Max0815. Did you try ?

Comment: wait ah my bad im slightly sleep deprived rn lol trying to solve this and I had forgotten that we only need to get rid of the $y$ not the $x$.

Comment: Man I dont know why I spent so much time trying so many convoluted substitutions when I couldve just done this one lol. BTW do you perhaps know why my original method had a limited domain(like which step in particular restricted it)?

Comment: wait ah nvm it was just me forgetting a plus minus when i square rooted bruh

Comment: @Max0815. Obviously, you were sleeping !